# How do I get all photos from a Facebook post using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When I use the Facebook API with FQL I have this query:

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'xxxx'
```

If the post has more than 9 pictures related to it, I only get data from the first 9.

I have tried setting both `limit` and `filter_key` in the query to see if it produces another result, but it does not.